# excel button is not showing in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have use following datatable code for excel,pdf and copy

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#order_table').DataTable( {
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
             {
                 extend: 'copyHtml5',
                 exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
             },
             {
                 extend: 'excelHtml5',
                 exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
             },
             {
                 extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                 exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
             }
         ]
     } );
   } );
 </script>
```

it show only copy button is any file remain to upload for show excel and pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taiwanhotdog/7ztkdof8/8/)
You need include all js here :

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
```

JS

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
});
```